# Редактирование бинарного кода изображения

Tags: стеганография, php, изображения

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане!
Недавно мне пришла в голову мысль реализовать 1 из методов [стеганографии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9C.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B4_LSB) на php.
Для этого мне понадобилась функция, которая позволяет работать напрямую с бинарным кодом картинки (крайне неудобно было бы делать это через цвета, каждый раз переводя кол-во каждого из цветов в десятичную систему и обратно в двоичную). Честно пытался найти такую функцию в интернете, возможно, я олень, но не вышло.
 Подскажите, если не сложно.

Comment: Если не подскажут готовых решений, то можете сделать так:  
1. Сохранить изображение как BMP в 16 битной глубине цвета без сжатия.  
2. Узнать размеры изображения.  
3. Отрезать от файла служебные заголовки.  
4. Работать с файлом как со строкой, где один пиксель обозначен 6-ю байтами.  
Довольно хорошо структура формата описана в [Вики]( http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP).

Comment: Не вполне понятно, что именно требуется. Открыть файл любой картинки и работать с массивом цветовых значений её пикселей? Посмотрите в любом случае, на ф-ии двух популярных библиотек для работы с изображениями в php: [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) и [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

Comment: Я хотел получить либо строку, состоящую чисто из 1 и 0, либо массив всех байт (ключом является номер, а значением - бинарное число с 8 разрядами). Вчера подумал и решил не париться и использовать библиотеку GD, получать цвет пикселя, а далее его обрабатывать. По сути, то же самое, только с бОльшим количеством промежуточных действий. Но спасибо за совет :) а о библиотеке ImageMagik я даже не слышал раньше, о_О

Comment: получить строку то из 1 и 0 вообще не лишние телодвижения ни разу))

Comment: М-да, вы правы :) зато обрабатывать удобно :D